# 사람들에 대한 조사를 했다 vs 사람들에 대해 조사했다

Tags: grammar

사람들에 대한 조사를 했다
Made investigation about people

사람들에 대해 조사했다
Investigated about people

Are both sentences correct? In first 대한 used like modificator, and in second 대해 acts like conjuction. Which variant sounds more natural?

Comment: Both sounds natural. I would say the latter more often but also sometimes say the former, and this is just a personal preference and others might prefer the former.

Comment: Both expressions are equally bad. I'm not saying that they are wrong but they are not recommended - in terms of how natural it may sound. I'd rather say "사람들을 조사했다".

Comment: I would avoid the use of 대하다. If you would like to be *more specific* and also comply with the standard, you should use 조사하다 with a *non-human* object, such as 성향, 행적, and 선호도 (for example, 사건 당시 사람들의 **행적**을 조사했다).

Comment: Thank you for explanation, I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

사람들에 대한 조사를 했다 vs 사람들에 대해 조사했다

I agree that both are natural for daily uses.
However, for formal occassions where conciseness matters, the latter serves better.
We usually avoid saying ~를 했다 for verbs when there is a shorter counterpart.

But as you know, in casual conversations, it doesn't really matter.